# Strategies for deleting or encrypting tmp data

Tags: systemd, tmpfs, dm-crypt

I have a Ubuntu 22.04 system with LUKS on LVM, with swap and a data volume encrypted (`/data`). This will eventually run on a VPS, with limited RAM (probably 2 or 4 GB), but a reasonable amount of disk space (>= 50 GB). I also need to encrypt tmp data, or at least ensure that it doesn't survive shut-down (to ensure that there's nothing sensitive in the disk backing file at the VPS provider).

*Question #1*: can I just symlink `/var/tmp` to `/data/var/tmp`, or will systemd complain about this? Does systemd actually care about `/var/tmp`?

*Question #2*: what about `/tmp`?

`/tmp` is currently a real directory on the root storage:

```
$ df /tmp/
Filesystem           1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg0-root  11141704 2838712   7715216  27% /
```

The Ubuntu default is that `tmpfs` is enabled for a number of other things, but not `/tmp`. I think my options on `/tmp` are:

1. Enable `tmpfs`; clean, but probably doesn't make sense if I've only got 2 or 4 GB. But, if the RAM is limited, maybe the tmp data will just be swapped out, which would be Ok, since `swap` is encrypted? Can `/tmp` be made "more swappy" than ordinary paging operations?
2. Symlink `/tmp` to `/data/tmp`, where it will be encrypted, but I'm guessing this is ether impossible or will require systemd setup
3. Create a new `/tmp` partition, encrypt it, put it in `fstab`. I don't really like this, because it's not flexible (how big? 100MB? 1GB?), and increases complexity.

Any ideas?